# Стоит обращаться к переменным внутри класса просто по имени или this.имя?

Tags: java

Допустим у нас есть код:

```
 public Clock(String cityName, int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {
            this.cityName = cityName;
            this.hours = hours;
            this.minutes = minutes;
            this.seconds = seconds;            
        }

        private void printTime() {
        System.out.println(String.format("В г. %s сейчас %d:%d:%d!", cityName, hours, minutes, seconds))
        }
```

Есть ли разница, обращаться к переменным класса внутри класса (в методе printTime, как вариант) просто по имени или this.имя, пожалуйста, подскажите?

Comment: Разницы нет. Всем командам приходится решать вопрос одновременного использования в коде метода его параметров и полей класса. Иногда поля класса записывают с префиксом `_field` или `mField`, иногда к полям обращаются через `this`. Лучше выбрать что-то одно, так удобнее читать код.

Answer (score 2):

Это имеет техническое значение только тогда, когда у нас есть локальная переменная с точно таким же именем. Тогда нужно использовать `this` для обращения к переменной класса. Если же его не будет, компилятор поймет это как обращение к локальной переменной.
А в общем - пишите, как вам удобнее. Но лучше делать это в едином стиле - использовать везде `this` или не использовать вовсе(за исключением случая, описанного выше).

Answer (score 0):

Если например в классе объявлено поле name и в методе также объявлено поле name, то при обращении к name без указания this, будет использоваться переменная объявленная в методе. Поэтому, чтобы не сделать случайно ошибку и не использовать поле метода в место поля класса, лучше при обращении к полям класса писать this.

```
public class Clock {
private String name = "Name 1";

private void printTime() {
     String name = "Name 2";
     System.out.println(this.name);
     System.out.println(name);
     }
```

> ```
> Out:
> Name 1
> Name 2
> ```